# Getting clicked cell value of table

Tags: php, jquery, html-table, cell

I have table defined like below. When user clicked any cell, the value of that cell which is defined by value = a.b.c.d need to be picked up by jQuery. For example, in first cell below, JQuery should pick a.b.c.d not ABCD. Problem I am facing is it is not showing any value, only gives "page at localhost says:" (Seems to be a blank variable here). Kindly somebody help me how to solve this issue.

```
<table id="tableID" border="1">
    <tr>
     <td bgcolor='blue'width='25%'>ABCD<input type=hidden name=name[] value = 'a.b.c.d'></td>
     <td bgcolor='blue'width='25%'>KLMN<input type=hidden name=name[] value = 'k.l.m.n'></td>    
    </tr>
</table>​
```

jQuery script

```
window.onload = init;
function init() 
{

$('#tableID').click(function(e){
    alert($(e.target).val());
})

}
```

Comment: your `input` misses the closing `>`

Comment: Closed it but still issue appearing.

Comment: Thanks, now it is showing value defined in value = 'a.b.c.d'. But when clicked any cell, getting same a.b.c.d

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/fzjev/53/